# confused with group testing

Tags: experiment-design, combinatorics

These are from notes,and I'm just very confused about what it tries to say 
[image]

[image]

Question 1: Does each test test all items? For example, if test 1 tested all items, test 2 tested all items etc, then why don't we just test all the items in one test?

Question 2: How do we determine whether each test is "+" or "-"? There are 10 items to be tested each time, with some positive and some negative, so how do we determine the final result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Each test only tests a pooled *sample* of the items. The sample for each test is given by the entries with 1 in the appropriate column. So for example, test 1 would test the pooled sample with items 1,2,3,4 and 5.

2) The simplifying assumption given is that "testing is 100% reliable". Hence a test will be "+" if at least one item in the pooled sample is actually "+".

In the example given, since only item 1 is actually "+", then a test will be "+" if it includes item 1 in the sample (and if not, then it will be "-").

Comment: Roberton Thank you for your answer.way better to understand than the note.